# SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure” feature workaround?

Tags: feature, publishing, infrastructure

I am running Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.. I have been trying to locate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure” features... This feature does not seem to be available on the Foundation version... Is there any work around for this? As I would like to make use of the ability to limit audiences and such like Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Steve.C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Targeting audience is also dependent on the User Profile service application, which again is not available in Foundations. Beyond this point, the Publishing Infrastructure is really a complex endeavour with many features, content types, web parts deployed with it.

In your situation, you might want to consider relying on either Permissions Levels assigned to various Security Groups, or Permissions Masks (e.g. in combination with SecurityTrimining sections) to replace Audiences, or user People/Groups and filter in your components based on that.  Examples could be found http://raiumair.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/security-trim-control/ or explanations http://sharepointgauravgoyal.blogspot.ch/2011/04/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.html

Also the use of [Me] via SharePoint Designer filter of the DataView web part could help.

Comment: Hi @C. Marius

Thank you for your reply. Very helpful.

Is there a way of implementing the Security Trimming Sections via the site setting or site administration pages?
Coding is not my strong point....

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Not really, you need to get at least to the level where SharePoint Designer is used! By coding, it might also work, again with SPD (see post updated or http://fusionovation.com/post/2008/09/18/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx or )